# Множественное создание файлов

Tags: консоль, powershell

Задача, создать за раз от десяти файлов и выше до нескольких сотен с одним именем с числовым индексом, прим. так: test-1.txt, test-2.txt и т. д. В справочнике PS на официальном сайте нашел решение вполне подходящее для нескольких файлов: New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path "c:\ps-test\test.txt", "c:\ps-test\Logs\test.log",но для десятков и сотен файлов решение мучительно трудное. Вразумите пжл, как в PS реализовать сию задачу без самоизнасилования. Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237558/5045688

Comment: То, что искал  Благодарствую 